# Cannot complete download from popup when prompting location with saveAs

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I've been working on a browser extension allowing users to generate epub files from any webpage.

To use the extension, a user has to click on a toolbar button which opens a **popup**. On the latter, after specifying a config, the user clicks on "Generate". Here is my issue though:

When I use the download API directly, and **specify `saveAs` to false** (i.e the user is NOT prompted where to save the file), then the download is completed as expected and the file saved in some location.

However, when I do set `saveAs` to true --- which is what I want in the final version --- then once the user has selected the location under which to save the file, the download fails. My intuition is that as soon as the file location window pops up, the popup looses focus and dies, which makes the download impossible to resume.

Is that the explanation? And is there a way to prevent such a problem? I do not find my use case to be much of a stretch, and do not get why popups associated with browser actions are not allowed to loose focus for file selection.

Another weird thing is that I'm pretty confident this problem only appeared recently in firefox, since when I started developing the extension, I had no issue.

Answer (score 0):

> My intuition is that as soon as the file location window pops up, the
>   popup looses focus and dies, which makes the download impossible to
>   resume.

That's right...

Browser Action Popup is page and once page is closed,  async operations will lose their reference. It is best to pass async operations to the background script.

- You can use
  [runtime.sendMessage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/runtime/sendMessage)
  to pass a message to the background script to run the download.
- You can also use the async
  [runtime.getBackgroundPage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/runtime/getBackgroundPage) to run a function in the background script but the first option works
  easier as you dont need to wait for the async response as in `runtime.getBackgroundPage()`